# PdfName.NM in iText TextField not Visible after calling setName()

Tags: itext, textfield

This is how I create a TextField in iText 5.

```
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TextField;

TextField tf = new TextField(stamper.getWriter(), rect, "fieldname");
tf.setText("fieldvalue");
tf.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
tf.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
tf.getTextField().setName("name_here");
stamper.addAnnotation(tf.getTextField(), 1);
```

This works. However, when I check in RUPS. PdfName.NM does not exist. setName() is the correct method, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that methods can be chained in iText 5, but that assumption is wrong. We introduced chained methods only in iText 7.

In iText 5, you need to split things up:

```
PdfFormField ff = tf.getTextField();
ff.setName("name_here");
stamper.addAnnotation(ff, 1);
```

The `PdfFormField` isn't a member-variable of the `TextField` class, and `getTextField()` isn't a real getter. When you trigger `getTextField()`, a new `PdfFormField` instance is created (iText is open source, just check for yourself if you're not sure).

iText 5 grew organically. I don't have a degree in computer sciences; I am self-taught in programming. If you look at the evolution of iText, you can see how my programming skills improved. If you want a really clean version of iText, please use iText 7.

Comment: Hi Bruno. Confirmed working. Thank you for the clarification.